# Displaying content on html by class using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add 2 clocks to a webpage. They both have the same class name and elements. Now, I want to countdown a time on both clocks from js.

But I am getting countdown on the left clock only. Time isn't updating/showing on the right clock. Now, how can I fix this? I know, this might be some dumb question. But I started javascript recently. So, forgive me if I am already doing something wrong in this code.

```js
countdown = (gap) => {
  console.log(gap);
  const second = 1000;
  const minute = 60 * second;
  const hour = 60 * minute;
  const day = 24 * hour;

  setInterval(() => {
    gap -= 1000;

    if (gap <= 0) return;

    const textDay = Math.floor(gap / day);
    const textHour = Math.floor((gap % day) / hour);
    const textMinute = Math.floor((gap % hour) / minute);
    const textSecond = Math.floor((gap % minute) / second);

    
    
    document.querySelector(".day").innerText = textDay;
    document.querySelector(".hour").innerText = textHour;
    document.querySelector(".minute").innerText = textMinute;
    document.querySelector(".second").innerText = textSecond;
  }, 1000);
};

countdown(50000000);
```

```css
h3
{
    display: inline;
}
div
{
    display: inline;    
}
body
{
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}
section
{
    display: inline;
    margin-inline: 5rem;   
}
#left
{    
    border: 2px solid green;
}
#right
{
    width: 2000vh;
    border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="left">
      <div class="container-day">
        <h3 class="day">Time</h3>
        <h3>Day</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="container-hour">
        <h3 class="hour">Time</h3>
        <h3>Hour</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="container-minute">
        <h3 class="minute">Time</h3>
        <h3>Minute</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="container-second">
        <h3 class="second">Time</h3>
        <h3>Second</h3>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="right">
        <div class="container-day">
          <h3 class="day">Time</h3>
          <h3>Day</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="container-hour">
          <h3 class="hour">Time</h3>
          <h3>Hour</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="container-minute">
          <h3 class="minute">Time</h3>
          <h3>Minute</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="container-second">
          <h3 class="second">Time</h3>
          <h3>Second</h3>
        </div>
      </section>

      <script src="/js.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Search for `querySelector` vs `querySelectorAll`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `querySelector` only returns the first occurrence of the element. To get all the elements, you need to  use `querySelectorAll`, which returns an array, and iterate over it, to change the `innerText` of each element.

```js
countdown = (gap) => {
  console.log(gap);
  const second = 1000;
  const minute = 60 * second;
  const hour = 60 * minute;
  const day = 24 * hour;

  setInterval(() => {
    gap -= 1000;

    if (gap <= 0) return;

    const textDay = Math.floor(gap / day);
    const textHour = Math.floor((gap % day) / hour);
    const textMinute = Math.floor((gap % hour) / minute);
    const textSecond = Math.floor((gap % minute) / second);

    
    
    document.querySelectorAll(".day").forEach(elem=>elem.innerText = textDay)
    document.querySelectorAll(".hour").forEach(elem=>elem.innerText = textHour)
    document.querySelectorAll(".minute").forEach(elem=>elem.innerText = textMinute)
    document.querySelectorAll(".second").forEach(elem=>elem.innerText = textSecond)
  }, 1000);
};

countdown(50000000);
```

```css
h3
{
    display: inline;
}
div
{
    display: inline;    
}
body
{
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}
section
{
    display: inline;
    margin-inline: 5rem;   
}
#left
{    
    border: 2px solid green;
}
#right
{
    width: 2000vh;
    border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="left">
      <div class="container-day">
        <h3 class="day">Time</h3>
        <h3>Day</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="container-hour">
        <h3 class="hour">Time</h3>
        <h3>Hour</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="container-minute">
        <h3 class="minute">Time</h3>
        <h3>Minute</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="container-second">
        <h3 class="second">Time</h3>
        <h3>Second</h3>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="right">
        <div class="container-day">
          <h3 class="day">Time</h3>
          <h3>Day</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="container-hour">
          <h3 class="hour">Time</h3>
          <h3>Hour</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="container-minute">
          <h3 class="minute">Time</h3>
          <h3>Minute</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="container-second">
          <h3 class="second">Time</h3>
          <h3>Second</h3>
        </div>
      </section>

      <script src="/js.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing `document.querySelector`, which only gets the first result. You have to use a more specified `querySelector`, by specifying the parent element.

```js
countdown = (gap,clock) => {
  console.log(gap);
  const second = 1000;
  const minute = 60 * second;
  const hour = 60 * minute;
  const day = 24 * hour;

  setInterval(() => {
    gap -= 1000;

    if (gap <= 0) return;

    const textDay = Math.floor(gap / day);
    const textHour = Math.floor((gap % day) / hour);
    const textMinute = Math.floor((gap % hour) / minute);
    const textSecond = Math.floor((gap % minute) / second);

    
    
    document.querySelector(clock+" .day").innerText = textDay;
    document.querySelector(clock+" .hour").innerText = textHour;
    document.querySelector(clock+" .minute").innerText = textMinute;
    document.querySelector(clock+" .second").innerText = textSecond;
  }, 1000);
};

countdown(50000000,"#left");
countdown(20000,"#right")
```

```css
h3
{
    display: inline;
}
div
{
    display: inline;    
}
body
{
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}
section
{
    display: inline;
    margin-inline: 5rem;   
}
#left
{    
    border: 2px solid green;
}
#right
{
    width: 2000vh;
    border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="left">
      <div class="container-day">
        <h3 class="day">Time</h3>
        <h3>Day</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="container-hour">
        <h3 class="hour">Time</h3>
        <h3>Hour</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="container-minute">
        <h3 class="minute">Time</h3>
        <h3>Minute</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="container-second">
        <h3 class="second">Time</h3>
        <h3>Second</h3>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="right">
        <div class="container-day">
          <h3 class="day">Time</h3>
          <h3>Day</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="container-hour">
          <h3 class="hour">Time</h3>
          <h3>Hour</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="container-minute">
          <h3 class="minute">Time</h3>
          <h3>Minute</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="container-second">
          <h3 class="second">Time</h3>
          <h3>Second</h3>
        </div>
      </section>

      <script src="/js.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```